# How to view SQLce script in Management Studio?

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I just installed SQL Server Management Studio 2008, to work with SQL-Compact. So I create a database, but how do I view the script so I can copy it into my code for programatically creating tables etc?

http://i53.tinypic.com/2wecnxg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems an add-in was needed, and this I believe does the work:

http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

And, maybe for working only with SQLCE this could be an alternative: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CEQuery.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**Right click on database -> Tasks -> Generate scripts -> NEXT ..**

Comment: where is "database" ? look image, seems no such option: http://i56.tinypic.com/2lmvrwg.png

Comment: how come I don't have this menu item?  Is there some add-on I need to install?

Comment: That is on ly an option for SQL Server objets, not SQL Server Compact objects